# REST web services and its Filters

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, spring-rest

I am studying Filter in REST web-services  and I have some confusion in postMatching and preMatching server Request filter , can any one clearly explain it ? when to use ?

Comment: Did you try to do something specific? Provide the code. Please create a [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

I think this excerpt from the Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) explains the difference really well:

***post-matching filters*** [...] would be applied only after a suitable resource method has been selected to process the actual request i.e. after request matching happens. Request matching is the process of finding a resource method that should be executed based on the request path and other request parameters. Since post-matching request filters are invoked when a particular resource method has already been selected, such filters can not influence the resource method matching process.

*To overcome the above described limitation, there is a possibility to mark a server request filter as a **pre-matching filter**, i.e. to annotate the filter class with the @PreMatching annotation. Pre-matching filters are request filters that are executed before the request matching is started. Thanks to this, pre-matching request filters have the possibility to influence which method will be matched.*